# How do you change the tempo midway through the song?

Tags: piano, tempo

I'm learning a song with a tempo of 170, and midway through it, this happens:
[image]

How do you adjust to a drastic change in tempo? Practice? But then will it throw off my rythm?

Comment: What score is this from? It's possible this is just an attempt to make a digital score (and its MIDI performance) create a believable *ritardando*, and what's really implied is just a slow down in the first two measures and a return to the original tempo in m. 61.

Comment: @Richard, It's from Waltz No. 2. There are other versions of it, but this is the best one I could find.

Comment: I think there should be an average fermata followed by a long one instead of the tempo change.

Comment: @TheNuckster - Do you mean the Shostakovich Waltz No. 2, or maybe some more obscure one like a Schubert or Brahms Waltz No. 2? Regardless, I don't think those tempo markings would be in a professional publisher's edition of that waltz.

Comment: Buy some sheet music printed on actual paper by a real music publisher.  I think you'll find those tempo  marks absent.  But in case they are not, the way you change tempo is ... you just change it.  It's *meant to be* a discontinuity in the meter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't take the numbers as gospel. It's just a slow down before picking up the original tempo again. A fermata in the trade!

I doubt the rall. will be the same every time, and that's not the important part. If it's just you playing, then slow down, and pick up again on bar 61.

Comment: I would strongly recommend the OP grab a couple other editions of whatever piece this is and see how they are marked.  This example is absurdly weird.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - yup! This seems like an 'up-to-date' computer generated version. They're only as good as the inputter - at best.

Comment: Music is not about Numeric Figures :P

Comment: @RishiNandha_M - that's nowhere near true. We use numbers to label just about everything musical. We even start songs 1,2,1,2,3,4...

Comment: Oh didn't mean it that way. Math and Music have intertwinings far more than visible at a topview. What I mean't was something like we don't do something like Sheet Music : "play(120bpm,sonata in C);" and we play at 120bpm exactly with no reference from anywhere.